# Babel script is not transformed

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to setup reactjs without npm.

I added three files before my JSX, nevertheless it gives me an error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Please help me understand what I missed. The code is below.

```js
"use strict";
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render( < h1 > Hello, world! < /h1>,
    document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<div id="react">Hi O'm HTNL!</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="react.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's because currently `import` is not something JS of your browser is aware of. If you're just looking for some sandbox solution to play around with react you can use [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads/single-file-example.html)  html file from Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @xmike comment I got that I shouldn't use import react, and react-dom because I've included them in the HTML file already. So without it everything works fine.